# Zuul: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: zuulserver.ZuulServerWrapper$1$1.isAsyncSupported()Z

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to write a Zuul filter that overrides the content of the request body. Here is what I have sofar. I only want to pass the harcoded string "useless" as body:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulServerWrapper {

@Bean
public ZuulFilter myFilter() {
    return new ZuulFilter() {

        @Override
        public Object run() {
            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getRequest();
            try {
                InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    String body = IOUtils.toString(is);
                    if (body != null) {
                        HttpServletRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                            public byte[] getContentData() {
                                return "useless".getBytes();
                            }
                            public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                                return new ServletInputStreamWrapper(getContentData());
                            }
                            public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
                                    String enc = "UTF-8";
                                    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(getContentData()), enc));
                            }
                        };
                        ctx.setRequest(wrappedRequest);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldFilter() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public int filterOrder() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public String filterType() {
            return "pre";
        }
    };
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulServerWrapper.class).web(true).run(
            args);
    }

}
```

Here is the curl request I am issuing:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"davidwalsh","password":"something"}' http://localhost:8080/poliana/index.html
```

My POM contains:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
```

When I issue this request, I end up getting the below exception:

```
   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: zuulserver.ZuulServerWrapper$1$1.isAsyncSupported()Z
 at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncSupported(ServletRequestWrapper.java:420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run(SendErrorFilter.java:84) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.postRoute(FilterProcessor.java:92) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.postRoute(ZuulRunner.java:87) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.postRoute(ZuulServlet.java:107) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:88) [zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
```

My two questions:

1) Is this the right approach to alter the request body in zuul?

2) How do I get rid of this exception?

EDIT: The above exception happens if I use com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper. alternaly I tried using javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper instead. When I do this, the execption I get a socket timeout exception instead. The full code with javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper is below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulServerWrapper {

    @Bean
    public ZuulFilter myFilter() {
        return new ZuulFilter() {

            @Override
            public Object run() {
                RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getRequest();
                try {
                    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
                    if (is != null) {
                        String body = IOUtils.toString(is);
                        System.out.println("Body: "+body);
                        if (body != null) {
                            HttpServletRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                                ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(getContentData());
                                public byte[] getContentData() {
                                    return "useless".getBytes();
                                }
                                public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                                    return new ServletInputStream() {
                                        @Override
                                        public int read() throws IOException {
                                            return bis.read();
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean isReady() {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean isFinished() {
                                            return bis.available()==0;
                                        }
                                    };
                                }
                            };
                            ctx.setRequest(wrappedRequest);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldFilter() {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public int filterOrder() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public String filterType() {
                return "pre";
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulServerWrapper.class).web(true).run(
                args); 
        }

}
```

EDIT 2: Adding my full POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>zuul-server-forward</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul Server</name>
<url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/</url>
<version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What version of spring cloud are you using? How are you deploying, embedded or standalone?

Comment: I am using Brixton.SR5. Added the full pom to the original post.

Comment: I am running it within Eclipse as an embedded spring boot app.